# How to extract certain parts of an HTML paragraph

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am new to webscraping and regular expressions and facing a problem here. One of my code gives me an output in HTML but I need to extract a certain part out of the paragraph and not the complete paragraph. I Need help with this. Below is my code.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("http://www.consultadni.info/index.php")
br.select_form(name="form1")
br['APE_PAT']='PATRICIO'
br['APE_MAT']='GAMARRA'
br['NOMBRES']='MARCELINA'
req=br.submit().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "lxml")
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
     sub=link.get("href")
     soup1 = BeautifulSoup(sub, "lxml")
     print soup1.find_all('p')
```

Output on screen:

```
[<p>/</p>]
[<p>datospersonales.php?nc=PATRICIO GAMARRA MARCELINA&amp;dni1=40772568&amp;dni2=12405868&amp;id1=12a40a58a68&amp;id2=30/06/1980&amp;dni3=40631880</p>]
[<p>datospersonales.php?nc=PATRICIO GAMARRA MARCELINA&amp;dni1=40772568&amp;dni2=12405868&amp;id1=12a40a58a68&amp;id2=30/06/1980&amp;dni3=40631880</p>]
[<p>http://www.infocorpperuconsultatusdeudas.blogspot.com/2015/05/infocorp-consulta-gratis-tu-reporte-de.html?ref=dnionline</p>]
```

What I need: `30/06/1980` & `40631880`

Comment: Try to parse `sub` with [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to get a dictionary of variables and values.

Comment: ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='tmp', params='', query='', fragment='')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='tmp', params='', query='', fragment='')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='tmp', params='', query='', fragment='')

Comment: I am new to regex, so what should be the regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python 2.7 try this way:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

result = set()

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
     sub = parse_qs(link.get("href"))

     if "id2" in sub:
         result.add((sub["id2"][0], sub["dni3"][0]))

print result
```

Comment: Andre this Doesn't work either. I modified my code, getting error
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0de445ee89d6> in <module>()
     14 for link in soup.find_all("a"):
     15      sub = parse_qs(link.get("href"))
---> 16      print sub["id2"][0], sub["dni3"][0]

KeyError: 'id2'

Comment: Ok. I modified the code adding a check. There may be some href without query.

Comment: Ok, let me try this one

Comment: Yo! this works, one last quick question, so the output gives me 2 repeated values (because that's how it comes in the browser as well) How can i omit the repeat value.
Example:
O/p is: 
30/06/1980 40631880
30/06/1980 40631880
And I need just: 30/06/1980 40631880

Comment: You can use store `(id2, dni3)` tuples in a set (which doesn't allow duplicates). I've updated the code.

Comment: Hey, the output is an empty file in this case :(

set([])

Comment: Oops. Try again ;)

Comment: This worked :) I wish I could upvote this, being a new member it says votes with less than 15 reputations are not shown!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Clean way to parse URLs (Python 3):

```
from urllib import parse

URL = "datospersonales.php?nc=PATRICIO GAMARRA MARCELINA&dni1=40772568&dni2=12405868&id1=12a40a58a68&id2=30/06/1980&dni3=40631880"

query_parts = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(URL).query)

print(query_parts["id2"][0], query_parts["dni3"][0])
```

Comment: Ah, this doesn't work for me in python 2.7.14 :(
I appreciate your help.
A quick question, the URL is the 2nd paragraph in the o/p. How do we just print the 2nd paragraph and not the others?

Comment: @Sandrachuz `find_all()` should return a regular Python list whose items can be accessed in the usual way.